# How to get the title of a column grid from a properties file in struts2-jquery plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, struts2, grid

I am using the grid component of the struts2-jquery plugin

http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag

and I need to get the title of the column from a properties file. Anyone have idea how to do that.

Note: in normal case without jquery plugin I get the value from properties file using the tag:

Comment: the tag i am using in normal case :<s:text name="addDate"/>

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the problem right you could use:

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="%{getText('addDate')}"/>
```